# 条件付き配列の割り振りに関するアイデア

Tags: array, julia

以下の2つの配列から新しい配列を作成する。

```
common_y = [1, 2]
new_y = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
```

意外と上手くいかず良いアイデアがありましたらご教授願いたく質問させていただきたいです。

**条件**
新しい配列を作る際に、common_yの要素に該当するnew_yの配列番号の要素を除きながら、new_yをコピーしていくことが目的です。common_yの配列が変化しても対応できるようになるべく一般化して書いています。
今自分が考えているのは、if条件で、合わないものを配列にしまわないという単純なことですが、それぞれの配列の長さが違うので変数を変える必要がありますが、変数がある値のときに必要ない結果まで出力してしまい悩んでいる状況です。

```
new_new_y = Int64[]
for i in minimum(new_y):maximum(new_y)
    for j in 1:length(common_y)
        if i == new_y[common_y[j]]
            continue
        else
            push!(new_new_y,i)
        end
    end
end
new_new_y
```

もう一つは、splice!を使って書こうと思ったのですが、for 文で回してしまうと、配列の長さが回すごとに代わってしまい結果が得られないという状況になってしまいます。

```
for i in 1:length(common_y)
        splice!(new_y,common_y[i])
end
```

シンプルですが、なかなか難しくて苦戦しています。
アドバイスありましたら、教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: `deleteat!()` ではどうでしょうか。`new_new_y ＝deleteat!(copy(new_y), common_y)`

Comment: 「common_yの要素番号に該当する配列yの要素」というのが何を意味するのか判りません。common_yの値は[1, 2]な訳ですが、[1, 2]で要素番号は何になりますか？

「配列yの要素を除きながら」という表記がありますが、質問に示されている配列はcommon_yとnew_yの二つだけで、配列ｙが何なのか判りません。

まず、質問をプログラムの内容と整合性があって、誰にでも意味が判る日本語に修正してください。

Comment: 要素番号は配列の順番(i = 1,2,,...,length(array))というつもりですが、y=[1,2]ならy[1]=1がnew_yの[1]番目に相当するということです。

Comment: 質問文の最初に入力の具体例が挙がっていますが、入力に `new` という名前がついているので誤解が生じているのではないかと思います。この `common_y` と `new_y` が入力されたときに期待される出力も冒頭に書いておくともっと良くなるのではと思いました。

Comment: 申し訳ないです、後日修正いたします

Answer (score 1):

`InvertedIndices`パッケージを使えば，あまりコードを書かずに実現できますね。

```
using InvertedIndices

common_y = [1, 2]
new_y = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
         19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]

new_new_y = new_y[Not(common_y)]
```